# How to get infinite diamond armour/tools without crafting/infinetly?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How to get diamond armour/tools without crafting? It would sound good to exist another way to get diamond equipment than crafting, both because digging diamonds is a bit too dangerous and that they might get rarer and rarer as I mine them.  **So, how can I get diamond equipment without having to mine?**

Comment: If your diamonds have run out, you must have explored a hell of a lot of the world. How did you end up going through approximately 28 trillion diamonds anyway?

Comment: I said "if diamonds were to run out" not "diamonds ran out", so it's indeed fictional. And anyway, it may be safer to have a direct source instead of digging deep into the ground. @angussidney

Comment: This question seems strained, and isn't something that can actually happen.  You'd be better off just asking what alternate methods there are of acquiring diamonds.

Comment: Right, on it. @Frank

Comment: Go to an end city. That's much safer than digging deep...

Comment: @angussidney Please note that alternative, renewable ways of earning something can be done in your cozy home. Example: You can buy Lapis Lazuli from a Cleric put in a safe area, instead of going deep in the mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 options for this:

- First, you can trade with villagers to get helmets, chestplates, swords, axes, shovels (spades) or pickaxes.
- Second, you can collect armour from Zombies and Skeletons, though the chances for it are small, initially 0.02% for diamond material, combined with the chances for full sets.

  The only diamond tool you can't buy or loot are hoes. (But who needs diamond hoes, anyway?)

Answer (score -1):

You could also use commands, and set them on a slow clock to fill a certain area with diamond ore for a certain amount of time, whether you use a fast clock or a slow clock to set off the command block.